# ¿Por qué si el método es invocado desde otra clase no muestra la etiqueta?

Tags: java

Estimados amigos tengo esta clase que me abre una ventana (la he quitado todos métodos no necesarios):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel.*;
import javax.swing.JButton.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
public class Panelito  extends JFrame{
    private ImagenFondo tapiz = new ImagenFondo();
    JPanel cultivos;
    public static void main(String []arg){
        Panelito panel = new Panelito();
        panel.marco();
        new Cultivo();
    }
    
    private class ImagenFondo extends JPanel{//Metemos la imagen
        private Image imagen;
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            imagen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("img/Parcelle_de_blé_tendre_à_.jpg")).getImage();
            g.drawImage(imagen, 0,0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
            setOpaque(false);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    }
    
    public Panelito(){//Constructor for objects of class Panelito
        cultivos = crearPaneles ("Cultivos", 36, 195, 940, 355, tapiz, true);
        etiquetas("C U L T I V O S", 30, 15, 918, 20, "Arial", Font.BOLD, 18, true, cultivos);
    }

    private void marco(){//Crear el marco
        this.setContentPane(tapiz);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(1024, 768);
        this.setTitle("Cooperativa empresarial");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    public JPanel crearPaneles(String nombre, int posX, int posY, int alto, int ancho, JPanel padre, boolean visible){//Crear los paneles
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        padre.add(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel.setBounds(posX, posY, alto, ancho);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setVisible(visible);
        panel.setName(nombre);
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void etiquetas(String texto, int posX, int posY, int ancho, int alto, String letra, int tipo, int grosor, boolean centrado, JPanel padre){
        JLabel textoEtiqueta = new JLabel(texto);
        padre.add(textoEtiqueta);
        textoEtiqueta.setBounds(posX, posY, ancho, alto);
        textoEtiqueta.setFont(new Font(letra, tipo, grosor));
        if (centrado == true){textoEtiqueta.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);}
        System.out.println(texto + " puesto en el panel " + padre);
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. Me muestra la ventana con la imagen de fondo, el panel y la etiqueta. Pero cuando llama a la clase Cultivo el método es invocado, lo termina, pero no se ve nada en el panel. Esta es la clase Cultivo:

```
import java.awt.Font;
public class Cultivo{
    
    public Cultivo(){//Constructor for objects of class Cultivo
        Panelito panel = new Panelito();
        panel.etiquetas("Texto creado desde una clase externa", 10, 100, 100, 50, "Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12, false, panel.cultivos);
        System.out.println("Etiqueta lanzada");
    }
}
```

¿Alguien me diría qué hago mal? He dejado el código lo más limpio posible y no parece la nueva etiqueta en el panel pese a que el método es invocado correctamente y finalizado.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: tu codigo esta incompleto con lo que agregas ni siquiera compila, te recomiendo siempre poner un [mcve]

Comment: en que panel??? el que creas dentro de la clase cultivo, y no pones en ninguna pantalla?? un objeto visual es como cualquier objeto... tenes que ponerlo en la pantalla.. ahi, no lo estas poniendo en ningun lado...

Comment: por cierto porque panelito no extiende directamente de JPanel? https://javapro.org/programming-languages/componente-personalizado-en-netbeans-beanform/

Comment: Es que si lo hago así el método 'marco' no deja de darme problemas con que no tiene la clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que se te olvidó llamar al método marco(), si agregas la llamada y cambias de "private" a "public" al método en cuestión, te creará otro frame, con la etiqueta correspondiente.

En **Cultivo**:

```
import java.awt.Font;

public class Cultivo {
    
    public Cultivo() {  
        Panelito panel = new Panelito();
        panel.marco();
        panel.etiquetas( "Texto creado desde una clase externa", 10, 100, 100, 50, "Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12, false, panel.cultivos );
        System.out.println( "Etiqueta lanzada" );
    }
}
```

En **Panelito**:

```
public void marco() {//Crear el marco
    this.setContentPane( tapiz );
    this.getContentPane().setLayout( null );
    this.setSize( 1024, 768 );
    this.setTitle( "Cooperativa empresarial" );
    this.setResizable( false );
    this.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    this.setVisible( true );
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
}
```

Para que no se cree un `frame` adicional, tenemos que hacer unas modificaciones.
El constructor de la clase **`Cultivo`** nos queda así:

```
public Cultivo( Panelito pp, JPanel cultivos ) {  //Constructor for objects of class Cultivo  
    pp.etiquetas( "Texto creado desde una clase externa", 10, 100, 100, 50, "Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12, false, cultivos );
    System.out.println("Etiqueta lanzada");
}
```

En **`Panelito`** hacemos los siguientes cambios:

```
static JPanel cultivos;

public static void main( String[] arg ) {
   Panelito panel = new Panelito();
   panel.marco();
   new Cultivo( panel, cultivos );
}
```

Resumiendo, declaramos **`cultivos`** estático, para poder usarlo dentro del **`main`**.
En el mismo, llamamos a la clase **`Cultivo`**, pasandole como parámetros, el objeto **`Panelito`** y el panel **`cultivos`**.
Dentro de **`Cultivos`**, usamos el objeto **`Panelito`** para poder llamar a su método **`etiquetas`**, al cual le pasamos entre otros parámetros, el panel **`cultivos`**.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Eso funcionó, pero así me irá creando un marco tras otro cada vez que llame a esa clase. Si no es abusar de tu paciencia ¿se puede hacer de alguna manera que ponga la etiqueta en el primer panel 'cultivo' creado?

Comment: @Zósimo, edité mi respuesta, para que se adapte a tus requerimientos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Marce. Quedan ya pocos tan buenos como tú. En todos los aspectos

Comment: Un placer poder ayudarte, y no, este sitio está lleno de gente con ganas de colaborar!!.